# How to join two dataframes by nearest time-date?

Tags: r, datetime, posixlt

I have 2 data sets, each containing a date-time value in POSIXlt format, and some other numeric and character variables.

I want to combine both data sets based on the date-time column.
But the date stamps of both data sets do not match, so I need to combine them by nearest date (before or after).
In my example, data value "e" from 2016-03-01 23:52:00 needs to be combined with "binH" at 2016-03-02 00:00:00, not "binG".

Is there a function that would allow me to combine my data sets by nearest date-time value, even if it is after?

I have found ways of combining dates to the next previous date using the cut() function, or the roll=Inf function in data.tables. But I couldn't get my timestamps into any format roll='nearest' would accept.

```
    >df1
    date1 value
    1 2016-03-01 17:52:00     a
    2 2016-03-01 18:01:30     b
    3 2016-03-01 18:05:00     c
    4 2016-03-01 20:42:30     d
    5 2016-03-01 23:52:00     e

    >df2
    date2 bin_name
    1 2016-03-01 17:00:00     binA
    2 2016-03-01 18:00:00     binB
    3 2016-03-01 19:00:00     binC
    4 2016-03-01 20:00:00     binD
    5 2016-03-01 21:00:00     binE
    6 2016-03-01 22:00:00     binF
    7 2016-03-01 23:00:00     binG
    8 2016-03-02 00:00:00     binH
    9 2016-03-02 01:00:00     binI
```

Comment: I hope you really meant POSIXct format. Storing POSIXlt vectors (which are really lists) in dataframes is a prescription for massive confusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`data.table` should work for this (can you explain the error you're coming up against?), although it does tend to convert POSIXlt to POSIXct on its own (perhaps do that conversion on your datetime column manually to keep `data.table` happy). Also make sure you're setting the key column before using `roll`.

(I've created my own example tables here to make my life that little bit easier. If you want to use dput on yours, I'm happy to update this example with your data):

```
new <- data.table( date = as.POSIXct( c( "2016-03-02 12:20:00", "2016-03-07 12:20:00", "2016-04-02 12:20:00" ) ), data.new = c( "t","u","v" ) )
head( new, 2 )

                  date data.new
1: 2016-03-02 12:20:00        t
2: 2016-03-07 12:20:00        u

old <- data.table( date = as.POSIXct( c( "2016-03-02 12:20:00", "2016-03-07 12:20:00", "2016-04-02 12:20:00", "2015-03-02 12:20:00" ) ), data.old = c( "a","b","c","d" ) )
head( old, 2 )


                  date data.old
1: 2016-03-02 12:20:00        a
2: 2016-03-07 12:20:00        b

setkey( new, date )
setkey( old, date )

combined <- new[ old, roll = "nearest" ]
combined

                  date data.new data.old
1: 2015-03-02 12:20:00        t        d
2: 2016-03-02 12:20:00        t        a
3: 2016-03-07 12:20:00        u        b
4: 2016-04-02 12:20:00        v        c
```

I've intentionally made the two tables different row lengths, in order to show how the rolling join deals with multiple matches. You can switch the way it joins with:

```
combined <- old[ new, roll = "nearest" ]
combined

                  date data.old data.new
1: 2016-03-02 12:20:00        a        t
2: 2016-03-07 12:20:00        b        u
3: 2016-04-02 12:20:00        c        v
```

Comment: @user2223405 did this solution work for you? Either way, make sure you don't just abandon your question. Come back and let us know what worked and what didn't.

Comment: I tried this approach in a similar case of mine, but the merge of the two datatables is wrong in my case. It seems that there is a lag of 2 hours. Meaning that the nearest datetime value between the two data.tables is always 2 hours, but in reality there are nearest datetime values.

Comment: @Stathis are both timestamp columns in the same timezone?

Comment: Yes, I guess, I mean that the values are in the same time zone, but not sure if I have to define the timezone before executing the code

Comment: The timezone is stored as an attribute of the column. If that attribute is different between the 2 columns you're comparing for the join, it could have the effect you're seeing. You can check the timezone attribute of a POSIXct column with `attr(dt$col, "tzone")`

Comment: I think that you helped me solve it. I just defined the timezone in each data.table as tz = "GMT" and the merge seems to have been executed smoothly. Still checking though, but it seems that the problem has been resolved. Thank you a lot

Comment: Owing an answer, it seems that the problem was solved. Many modifications were required because the data had a certain pattern that was needed to be followed in order to have the utc time, but after those modifications the results seems to be correct. So, concluding the answer in this question is really valid and helpful. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but instead of using `data.table` or `tidyverse` I created my own function `amerge` for "approximate merge". It takes 4 arguments:

- two data frames,
- a vector of column names for "firm" (not approximate) merge - these must exist in both data frames,
- and the name of a single column (in both data frames) for approximate merge. It will work for any numeric values, including dates.

The idea was to merge rows 1-to-1 of best matches, and not loose any rows from any data frame. Here is my commented code with a working example.

```
amerge <- function(d1, d2, firm=NULL, approx=NULL) {
  rt = Sys.time()

  # Take care of conflicting column names
  n2 = data.frame(oldname = names(d2), newname = names(d2))
  n2$newname = as.character(n2$newname)
  n2$newname[(n2$oldname %in% names(d1)) & !(n2$oldname %in% firm)] =
    paste(n2$newname[(n2$oldname %in% names(d1)) & !(n2$oldname %in% firm)], "2", sep=".")

  # Add unique row IDs
  if (length(c(firm, approx))>1) {
    d1$ID1 = factor(apply(d1[,c(approx,firm)], 1, paste, collapse=" "))
    d2$ID2 = factor(apply(d2[,c(approx,firm)], 1, paste, collapse=" "))
  } else {
    d1$ID1 = factor(d1[,c(approx,firm)])
    d2$ID2 = factor(d2[,c(approx,firm)])
  }

  # Perform initial merge on the 'firm' parameters, if any
  # Otherwise match all to all
  if (length(firm)>0) {
    t1 = merge(d1, d2, by=firm, all=T, suff=c("",".2"))
  } else {
    names(d2)= c(n2$newname,"ID2")
    t1 = data.frame()
    for (i1 in 1:nrow(d1)) {
      trow = d1[i1,]
      t1 = rbind(t1, cbind(trow, d2))
    }
  }

  # Match by the most approximate record
  if (length(approx)==1) {
    # Calculate the differential for approximate merging
    t1$DIFF = abs(t1[,approx] - t1[,n2$newname[n2$oldname==approx]])
    # Sort data by ascending DIFF, so that best matching records are used first
    t1 = t1[order(t1$DIFF, t1$ID1, t1$ID2),]
    t2 = data.frame()
    d2$used = 0
    # For each record of d1, find match from d2
    for (i1 in na.omit(unique(t1$ID1))) {
      tx = t1[!is.na(t1$DIFF) & t1$ID1==i1,]
      # If there are non-missing records, get the one with minimum DIFF (top one)
      if (nrow(tx)>0) {
        tx = tx[1,]
        # If matching record found, remove it from the pool, so it's not used again
        t1[!is.na(t1$ID2) & t1$ID2==tx$ID2, c(n2$newname[!(n2$newname %in% firm)], "DIFF")] = NA
        # And mark it as used
        d2$used[d2$ID2==tx$ID2] = 1
      } else {
        # If there are no non-missing records, just get the first one from the top
        tx = t1[!is.na(t1$ID1) & t1$ID1==i1,][1,]
      }
      t2 = rbind(t2,tx)
    }
  } else {
    t2 = t1
  }
  # Make the records the same order as d1
  t2 = t2[match(d1$ID1, t2$ID1),]
  # Add unmatched records from d2 to the end of output
  if (any(d2$used==0)) {
    tx = t1[t1$ID2 %in% d2$ID2[d2$used==0], ]
    tx = tx[!duplicated(tx$ID2),]
    tx[, names(d1)[!(names(d1) %in% c(firm))]] = NA
    t2 = rbind(t2,tx)
    t2[is.na(t2[,approx]), approx] = t2[is.na(t2[,approx]), n2$newname[n2$oldname==approx]]
  }
  t2$DIFF = t2$ID1 = t2$ID2 = NULL
  cat("* Run time: ", round(difftime(Sys.time(),rt, "secs"),1), " seconds.\n", sep="")
  return(t2)
}
```

And the example:

```
new <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2), date = as.POSIXct( c("2016-03-02 12:20:00", "2016-03-07 12:20:00", "2016-04-02 12:20:00", "2016-04-12 11:03:00")), new = c("t","u","v","x"))
old <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1), date = as.POSIXct( c("2016-03-07 12:20:00", "2016-04-02 12:20:00", "2016-03-01 10:09:00", "2015-04-12 10:09:00","2016-03-03 12:20:00")), old = c("a","b","c","d","e"))

amerge(old, new, firm="ID", approx="date")
```

It outputs:

```
   ID                date  old              date.2  new
2   1 2016-03-07 12:20:00    a 2016-03-07 12:20:00    u
6   1 2016-04-02 12:20:00    b 2016-04-02 12:20:00    v
7   1 2016-03-01 10:09:00    c                <NA> <NA>
10  1 2015-04-12 10:09:00    d                <NA> <NA>
13  1 2016-03-03 12:20:00    e 2016-03-02 12:20:00    t
16  2 2016-04-12 11:03:00 <NA> 2016-04-12 11:03:00    x
```

So works for my purpose as intended - there is exactly one copy of each row from both data frames - matched by shortest time difference. One note: the function copies `date.2` into `date` column where the `date` would be missing.