# extract data from another data frame based on nearest timestamp and conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have two data frames. My first data frame looks like this :

```
TIME                TYPE    CATEGORY
2020-10-11 10:09:12 A       GOOD
2020-10-11 10:09:28 B       AVG
2020-10-11 10:10:18 C       WORST
2020-10-12 10:09:12 B       AVG
2020-10-12 10:12:09 A       GOOD
2020-10-13 12:03:23 A       AVG
2020-10-13 13:09:23 B       GOOD
2020-10-13 13:16:07 C       GOOD
```

The second data frame looks like this(In real data more data points are available) :

```
timestamp           value1  value2  type
2020-10-11 10:09:10 100     109     A
2020-10-11 10:09:14 120     123     B
2020-10-11 10:09:20 90      134     A
2020-10-11 10:09:25 113     165     B
2020-10-11 10:09:34 100     111     C
2020-10-11 10:10:01 120     123     C
2020-10-11 10:10:07 90      113     A
2020-10-11 10:10:35 113     109     C
2020-10-11 10:11:10 100     109     B
2020-10-11 10:11:34 120     165     A
2020-10-12 10:09:20 90      178     B
2020-10-12 10:12:19 113     145     A
2020-10-12 10:12:21 100     108     B
2020-10-12 12:09:15 120     109     C
2020-10-13 11:59:03 90      134     C
2020-10-13 12:01:23 113     176     B
2020-10-13 12:03:14 100     198     A
2020-10-13 12:03:44 120     109     C
2020-10-13 13:09:20 90      105     B
2020-10-13 10:09:26 113     110     B
2020-10-13 13:16:20 100     102     C
2020-10-13 13:16:40 120     167     A
```

Expected output is to extract columns `timestamp`, `value1` , `value2` based on nearest timestamp occurrences (both the sides) and type :

```
TIME                   TYPE     CATEGORY        timestamp       value1      value2
2020-10-11 10:09:12     A       GOOD        2020-10-11 10:09:10     100     109
2020-10-11 10:09:28     B       AVG         2020-10-11 10:09:25     113     165
2020-10-11 10:10:18     C       WORST       2020-10-11 10:10:35     113     109
2020-10-12 10:09:12     B       AVG         2020-10-12 10:09:20     90      178
2020-10-12 10:12:09     A       GOOD        2020-10-12 10:12:19     113     145
2020-10-13 12:03:23     A       AVG         2020-10-13 12:03:14     100     198
2020-10-13 13:09:23     B       GOOD        2020-10-13 13:09:20     90      105
2020-10-13 13:16:07     C       GOOD        2020-10-13 13:16:20     100     102
```

I tried something like :

```
t.first$nearest_time<- unlist(mapply(x = t.first$TIME, y = t.first$type, FUN = function(x, y) as.character(t.second$timestamp[which.min(abs(x - t.second$timestamp))])))
```

But I am unable to add conditions

Comment: You can try this `data.table` approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282749/r-how-to-join-two-data-frames-by-nearest-time-date

Comment: @RonakShah, this is partially working. This works with respect to date alone. How can I include `type` column as a condition. ie, `type == TYPE` value

Comment: It worked! Thanks