# R Merge two data frames based on nearest date and time match

Tags: r, date, time, merge, posixct

I've seen various solutions for this question based on date only, but the time component is tripping me up. I have two data frames with POSIXct columns called 'datetime'. For DF1 that column has data rounded to the nearest hour. For DF2, the time component is not rounded to the nearest hour and can occur anytime. The dataframes look like this:

DF1

| datetime | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-01 03:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2020-09-02 12:00:00 | 12 | 3 | 5 |
| 2020-09-02 22:00:00 | 4 | 9 | 19 |
| 2020-09-03 01:00:00 | 4 | 10 | 2 |
| 2020-09-04 06:00:00 | 4 | 12 | 1 |
| 2020-09-04 08:00:00 | 11 | 13 | 10 |

DF2

| datetime | Var |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-09-01 02:23:14 | A |
| 2020-09-01 03:12:09 | B |
| 2020-09-02 11:52:15 | A |
| 2020-09-02 12:15:44 | B |
| 2020-09-02 22:31:56 | A |
| 2020-09-02 21:38:05 | B |
| 2020-09-03 01:11:39 | A |
| 2020-09-03 00:59:33 | B |
| 2020-09-04 05:12:19 | A |
| 2020-09-04 06:07:09 | B |
| 2020-09-04 08:22:28 | A |
| 2020-09-04 07:50:17 | B |

What I want is to merge these two dataframes based on this column using the date and time that are closest in time to 'datetime' in DF1, so that it looks like this:

| datetime | X | Y | Z | Var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-01 03:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 4 | B |
| 2020-09-02 12:00:00 | 12 | 3 | 5 | A |
| 2020-09-02 22:00:00 | 4 | 9 | 19 | B |
| 2020-09-03 01:00:00 | 4 | 10 | 2 | B |
| 2020-09-04 06:00:00 | 4 | 12 | 1 | B |
| 2020-09-04 08:00:00 | 11 | 13 | 10 | B |

Thank you!

Comment: I apologize, but I was able to hunt down a previous question that was very similar and provided a useable answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282749/r-how-to-join-two-data-frames-by-nearest-time-date

Answer (score 2):

Adding helper columns for `merge` and `group_by`, using `merge` and then `dplyr` for the filtering

```
library(dplyr)

df1$tmp <- as.Date(df1$datetime)
df2$tmp <- as.Date(df2$datetime)

df1$grp <- 1:(nrow(df1))

merge(df1, df2, "tmp") %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  slice(which.min(abs(difftime(datetime.x, datetime.y)))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(tmp,grp,datetime.y))
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  datetime.x              X     Y     Z Var  
  <chr>               <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1 2020-09-01 03:00:00     1     3     4 B    
2 2020-09-02 12:00:00    12     3     5 A    
3 2020-09-02 22:00:00     4     9    19 B    
4 2020-09-03 01:00:00     4    10     2 B    
5 2020-09-04 06:00:00     4    12     1 B    
6 2020-09-04 08:00:00    11    13    10 B
```

##### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(datetime = c("2020-09-01 03:00:00", "2020-09-02 12:00:00", 
"2020-09-02 22:00:00", "2020-09-03 01:00:00", "2020-09-04 06:00:00", 
"2020-09-04 08:00:00"), X = c(1L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 11L), Y = c(3L, 
3L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L), Z = c(4L, 5L, 19L, 2L, 1L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(datetime = c("2020-09-01 02:23:14", "2020-09-01 03:12:09", 
"2020-09-02 11:52:15", "2020-09-02 12:15:44", "2020-09-02 22:31:56", 
"2020-09-02 21:38:05", "2020-09-03 01:11:39", "2020-09-03 00:59:33", 
"2020-09-04 05:12:19", "2020-09-04 06:07:09", "2020-09-04 08:22:28", 
"2020-09-04 07:50:17"), Var = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: This solution works just fine, but is a bit convoluted compared to the answer above which I finally found. Thank you for the effort and sorry for the time waste.

Comment: @Jacob K, no worries. If you check all the answers, we now have a `data.table` solution, a self made merge function and this `dplyr` approach. So fortunately no redundancy here :)